# How to minus one colum to another in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Have two query with response:

```
select value_name,SUM(value_count) as value_count
from dbo.tbl1
where session_id = @session_id
GROUP BY value_name

value_name , value_count
val1       ,    10
val2       ,    15
val3       ,    30
```

and

```
select value_name,SUM(value_count) as value_count
from dbo.tbl2
where session_id = @session_id
GROUP BY value_name

value_name , value_count
val1       ,    5
val2       ,    4
val3       ,    6
```

Both have same structure, want update tbl1 and set difference between same columns , somethig like:

```
UPDATE dbo.tbl1
SET tbl1.value_count - tbl2.value_count
```

Response must be when i will select tbl1 :

```
   value_name , value_count
    val1       ,    5
    val2       ,    11
    val3       ,    24
```

How to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this should do it (i didn't tested it)

```
select a.value_name, (a.value_count - b.value_count) as value_count

from (select value_name,SUM(value_count) as value_count
        from dbo.tbl1
        where session_id = @session_id
        GROUP BY value_name) a

inner join (
select value_name,SUM(value_count) as value_count
        from dbo.tbl2
        where session_id = @session_id
        GROUP BY value_name) b on a.value_count = b.value_count
```